# How to configure /usr/share/oem/grub.cfg on core-os by using ignition?

Tags: coreos, coreos-ignition

I try to configure /usr/share/oem/grub.cfg at first boot,
but it not do what I intent to do.
It just mount and edit on another path.
Any suggestion please.

log_file:
May 03 02:56:01 localhost ignition[473]: files: createFilesystemsFiles: createFiles: op(8): [started]  mounting "/dev/disk/by-label/OEM" at "/tmp/ignition-files983303341"
May 03 02:56:01 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs (sda6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
May 03 02:56:01 localhost ignition[473]: files: createFilesystemsFiles: createFiles: op(8): [finished] mounting "/dev/disk/by-label/OEM" at "/tmp/ignition-files983303341"
May 03 02:56:01 localhost ignition[473]: files: createFilesystemsFiles: createFiles: op(9): [started]  appending to file "/usr/share/oem/grub.cfg2"
May 03 02:56:01 localhost ignition[473]: files: createFilesystemsFiles: createFiles: op(9): [finished] appending to file "/usr/share/oem/grub.cfg2"
May 03 02:56:01 localhost ignition[473]: files: createFilesystemsFiles: createFiles: op(a): [started]  unmounting "/dev/disk/by-label/OEM" at "/tmp/ignition-files983303341"
May 03 02:56:01 localhost ignition[473]: files: createFilesystemsFiles: createFiles: op(a): [finished] unmounting "/dev/disk/by-label/OEM" at "/tmp/ignition-files983303341"

### config_file: ignition.yml

```
storage:  

  filesystems:
    - name: oem
        mount:  
        device: /dev/disk/by-label/OEM  
        format: ext4  
        label: OEM  

  files: 
    - filesystem: oem  
      path: grub.cfg  
      mode: 0644  
      append: true  
      contents:  
        inline: |  
          set linux_append="ipv6.disable=1"
```

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/bzub/edfd2a69d47de1fa3375d9e855ccc272

I found an answer.

path: grub.cfg --> path: /grub.cfg